# The getter 'value' isn't defined for the type 'DatabaseEvent'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

i have this problem at line  snapshot.value

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    databaseReference
        .child('ESP32_Device')
        .once()
        .then((DatabaseEvent snapshot) {
      double temp = snapshot.value['Temperature']['Data'];
      double humidity = snapshot.value['Humidity']['Data'];
      isLoading = true;
      _DashboardInit(temp, humidity);
    });
  }
```

photo of problem

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems null issue, try like this

```dart
double temp =
    double.tryParse("${snapshot?.value['Temperature']['Data']}") ?? 0.0;
double humidity =
    double.tryParse("${snapshot?.value['Humidity']['Data']}") ?? 0.0;
```

Comment: Also try  making it nullable  `DatabaseEvent? snapshot`

Comment: can u see my project when i do this solution i have a lot of of new problemshttps://github.com/Omarsevenway01/flutter-app.git

Comment: https://github.com/Omarsevenway01/flutter-app.git

Comment: https://github.com/Omarsevenway01/flutter-app.git

Comment: are you using null-safety ? your project seems old

Comment: i need to correct this project

Comment: any solutions? to run this application

Comment: I will prefer upgrading the project, More about [migration-guide](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide)

Comment: i dont now how to upgrade the project just i change depencies version but the project still not working do u have any solutions for that

Comment: you can do a trick if it doesnt contains others configuration, copy the project and run `flutter create .`(has dot at end)  after migration

Comment: m beginner in flutter when i can run flutter create

Comment: u can modify in my github repostory?

Comment: I can give a try by forking(not now), but you won't learn anything from it. Follow the migration guide, it should fix the issue.

Comment: Seems like it is not helping, rather than helping on cheating, I will pass. give a try , you can do it,

Answer (score 0):

Just because you create a variable named `snapshot` doesn't mean it is one, it is still a DatabaseEvent, not a snapshot.

I suggest you call the variable `event`, then use `event.snapshot.value` to access what you need.

Going forward I would recommend that you name variables for what they actually are eg somethingList (you can use plural instead here), somethingEvent, etc. It will save you, and other readers of your code, a lot of confusion. Point is to name stuff so that you know what it is.